# Perl socket receiving 301 http code

Tags: perl, sockets, http, http-headers

I am using a perl socket to request a page, the response I am getting back however is a 301 moved page, but the location it gives is the same one I am requesting. Does anyone know why this is happening and what header I should send to avoid the 301?

```
GET /security/data/oval/com.redhat.rhsa-all.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: redhat.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*

HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.redhat.com/security/data/oval/com.redhat.rhsa-all.xml
Server: BigIP
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location is not the same. The Hostname is different.

You are asking for `redhat.com`, it is telling you to go to `www.redhat.com`.

Comment: changing Host to www.redhat.com yields the same result

Comment: I get the same result as you when I use `redhat.com` and get an XML document when I use `www.redhat.com`. Note that you have to open a socket to `www.redhat.com` as it is not served by the same IP address as `redhat.com`.

Comment: oh woops, I forgot to set it when creating the socket,  you are right.

Comment: How come you're not using an existing web library (e.g. LWP)?